# Group by a table then add another tables count into the first table grouped count

Tags: sql

I want to group by the First table then add the result of the second and third table with the grouped count... But with a dummy servicecode

```
select servicecode, Count(*) as count from servicerequest
    where To_Char(CREATEDATE,'YYYY') = 2018
    and status = 50
    group by servicecode

        union

    select Count(*) as count from CERTREQUEST
     WHERE to_char(REQDATE,'yyyy') = 2018
    and service = 1

        union

    select Count(*) as count from LTR
     WHERE to_char(REQDATE,'yyyy') = 2018
    and Service = 1
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. I advise you read the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) article as it provides very useful information for newcomers on how to write questions. Quality questions help us provide you quality answers - I understand what you want to achieve but what is the issue you are experiencing with your SQL script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just select it in two other queries like that:

```
select servicecode, Count(*) as count from servicerequest
    where To_Char(CREATEDATE,'YYYY') = 2018
    and status = 50
    group by servicecode

        union

    select 1, Count(*) as count from CERTREQUEST
     WHERE to_char(REQDATE,'yyyy') = 2018
    and service = 1

        union

    select 2, Count(*) as count from LTR
     WHERE to_char(REQDATE,'yyyy') = 2018
    and Service = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

make parameter number same i make use emty string as i assumed `servicecode` is varchar put here value according to data type

```
select servicecode, Count(*) as count from servicerequest
    where To_Char(CREATEDATE,'YYYY') = 2018
    and status = 50
    group by servicecode

        union all

    select '', Count(*) as count from CERTREQUEST
     WHERE to_char(REQDATE,'yyyy') = 2018
    and service = 1

        union all

    select '',Count(*) as count from LTR
     WHERE to_char(REQDATE,'yyyy') = 2018
    and Service = 1
```

And i prefer union all

Comment: Just a small point (too small for me to be able to edit) - you're missing a comma between `'' Count(*)` in the third query. Also worth mentioning that `UNION ALL` preserves duplicate rows whilst `UNION` will aggregate them out. The OP may not be aware of this.